# Discrecte Mathematic Modular Aritmtric

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all integers $x$ such that $$12x + 13 ≡ 10(\mod51)$$.

I have a little problem first treated like a equatio
$$12x +13-13 ≡ 10-13 \mod(51)$$
$$12x ≡-3 \mod(51)$$ 
And i thougt with modular like add the right side $-3 + 51$
$$12x ≡ 48 \mod(51)$$ and i divided with 12 on both sides
i got this $$x = 4 \mod(51)$$ but in the answer was like this 
$x = 4 + 17k$ where did $17k$ come from

Comment: "where did 17k come from". I came from $51=3\cdot 17$, and $ x\equiv 4\bmod 17$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have

$$12x=48+51a$$ where $a$ is any integer

$$\iff12(x-4)=17a$$

As $(12,17)=1$

$$17|(x-4)\iff x\equiv4\pmod{17}$$

Comment: You move 48 to the left side how does you get 17?